# MVC Default Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, routes

I have home controller as default page with below routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Home",
      url: "{Home}/{Index}/{lang}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

But When i go to other page and try below hyperlink from view

```
<a  href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {id = id } )"></a>
```

its just redirect to home controller with below url `http://localhost:57457?id=1160`  but I wanted it to be as `http://localhost:57457/Home?id=1160`

Comment: `@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {id = id })` will generate `http://localhost:57457/Home/Index?id=1160` - not the url you are claimig. And your `Home` route makes no sense - it is identical to the `Default` route - i.e. it matches any url with between 0 and 3 segments so the 2nd route will never be hit.

Comment: If you want `http://localhost:57457/Home?id=1160` then you need to generate a specific route before the default route - `routes.MapRoute( name: "Home", url: "Home/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });`